# splice is not a function

Tags: javascript, funciones

Estoy utilizando el método `splice` para eliminar objetos dentro del array este es mi codigo:

```
        let imagenes = [];

        $(document).on("change", "#add-new-photo", function () {
         let files = this.files;  
         var contenedor;



          for (var x = 0; x < files.length; x++) {//se recorre el array
             contenedor = files[x];//se guarda el array
             console.log(contenedor);
             imagenes.push(contenedor);//se insertan los arrays

            }
           const elimanado = files.splice(1, 1);  //updated
           console.log(eliminado);
           console.log(files);
      });
```

y este es el resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿porque sucede? y ¿como puedo solucionarlo?

Comment: asegurate que la variable `files` sea un array, para mas información puedes leer la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice)

Answer (score 0):

Si la variable a la que estas intentando remover el elemento no es un arreglo obtendrás `variable.slice is not a function`.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).